# Where should I define constants for Spring's @Qualifier annotations?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection

Spring's dependency injection allows distinguishing multiple implementations for the same interface with the `@Qualifier("<flavor>")` annotation.

For example, we could have:

```
public class Consumer {
  @Autowired("b") private SomeInterface dependency;
}

public interface SomeInterface { }

@Component @Qualifier("a")
public class VariantA implements SomeInterface { }

@Component @Qualifier("b")
public class VariantB implements SomeInterface { }
```

This requires that both, the consumer, and the implementations, use the same constant Strings to identify the variants, in this example "a" and "b". As a clean coder, my first impulse is to create constants for these Strings.

**But where should I put them?**

### A. Consumer

Putting them in the Consumer is out of the question, because that would invert the dependency in an illegal direction, requiring the implementations to know their consumers:

```
public class Consumer {
  public final static String VARIANT_B = "b";
  @Autowired(Consumer.VARIANT_B) private SomeInterface dependency;
}

@Component @Qualifier(Consumer.VARIANT_B)
public class VariantB implements SomeInterface { }
```

### B. Implementation

Putting them in the implementations seems also to be besides the point, reintroducing the consumer-knows-implementation dependency that dependency injection wants to remove in the first place:

```
public class Consumer {
  @Autowired(VariantB.VARIANT_B) private SomeInterface dependency;
}

@Component @Qualifier(VariantB.VARIANT_B)
public class VariantB implements SomeInterface {
  public final static String VARIANT_B = "b";
}
```

### C. Interface

Putting them in the interface seems to be an option, but is only possible if the interface is mine and I am free to change it. Also, the notion of having the interface "know" all its implementation variants beforehand sounds a little strange.

```
public class Consumer {
  @Autowired(SomeInterface.VARIANT_B) private SomeInterface dependency;
}

public interface SomeInterface {
  public final static String VARIANT_A = "a";
  public final static String VARIANT_B = "b";
}

@Component @Qualifier(SomeInterface.VARIANT_A)
public class VariantA implements SomeInterface { }

@Component @Qualifier(SomeInterface.VARIANT_B)
public class VariantB implements SomeInterface { }
```

### D. Constants class

The cleanest solution seems to be putting the constants into a separate development object. This looks a little overhead-y, however:

```
public class Consumer {
  @Autowired(ImplementationVariant.B) private SomeInterface dependency;
}

public interface SomeInterface { }

public class ImplementationVariant {
  public final static String A= "a";
  public final static String B= "b";
}

@Component @Qualifier(ImplementationVariant.A)
public class VariantA implements SomeInterface { }

@Component @Qualifier(ImplementationVariant.B)
public class VariantB implements SomeInterface { }
```

Answer (score 2):

## E. Use you own annotations

See my answer here: [Typesafe @Qualifier for Spring Boot to avoid errors with strings](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69263925/9224219) for details.

Create you own annotations like

```
@Qualifier("a")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface VariantA {}

@Qualifier("b")
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface VariantB {}
```

Then use them like this:

```
@Autowired
@VariantB
private SomeInterface dependency;

@Component
@VariantA
public class VariantA implements SomeInterface { }

@Component
@VariantB
public class VariantB implements SomeInterface { }
```

Answer (score 0):

I would choose E : the standard way.

Adding this indirection to identify `beans` names adds boiler plate code, is not standard (your peers will be surprised) and  is not robust either.
Why no robust ? A qualifier expects a string and not an enum value that is strongly bounded. It means that you could pass an incorrect string such as `@Component @Qualifier(OtherImplementationVariant.B)` and it will still compile fine.

A more robust alternative to achieve that would be to favor the `@Bean` method factory for beans that have and that use `@Qualifier` and so to set dependencies between beans by invoking the `@Bean` method.  But there still, that is verbose and not standard at all to generalize them for such a requirement.   So not a good idea either.

So I think that you should just stick to standards because if a mismatch occurs and that a dependency cannot be resolved, **the issue will be detected as soon as the spring boot startup**.

Comment: So there will be duplicate Strings in class and caller ?

Comment: @user7294900 Yes. Duplication is bad but some duplication are acceptable. And here I think that we are in that case.